# refresh activity with updated variables

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-sqlite, refresh

I can't quite find my answer on here to this question but I have an activity with a `ListView` from a Database.

```
String ascOrDescFilter = " ASC";
String columnFilter = "amount";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    dbList= new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    dbList = helper.getDataFromFilteredDB(columnFilter, ascOrDescFilter);`
```

I want to refresh my activity while putting in updated variables that the user can change in a context menu.

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.schedule:
            columnFilter="spare1";
            ascOrDescFilter= " ASC";
            //dbList = helper.getDataFromFilteredDB("spare1", " ASC");
            onRestart();
            return true;
        case R.id.amount:
            columnFilter="spare1";
            ascOrDescFilter= " ASC";
            //dbList = helper.getDataFromFilteredDB("balance", " DESC");;
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I need to call onRestart or onResume? but I'm unsure how to implement these for my activity. Do I need an intent? As you can see from the above program I've tried it with an onStart method (and onResume + onRecreate) but nothing will get my Listview to refresh.

```
   @Override
public void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

//@Override
protected void onRecreate() {
    super.onResume();
    this.onCreate(null);
}
```

Thanks, any pointers would be most helpful. This is my first app I've developed on my own.

Comment: No need to restart your activity. Just update the list view. Like the commented part in your code. Does it work? And if not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an Adapter with your ListView and when you change the data, just update the data in the list and call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

If you want to write your own Adapter, extend it from BaseAdapter else ArrayAdapter is the most simplest to use.

This might get you started with adapters: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as correct answer although notifyDataSetChanged() did not work for me entirely. I have what I want working but I'll have to examine the code and figure out what exactly is going on. I've been stumped on this since Thursday so really both replies were helpful. @Schokokuchen Bäcker I was messing about with code to try and work out what was going wrong, I know the values don't match up but that code should have worked if notifyDataSetChanged was implemented. I was thinking onResume or onRestart was my solution so thanks both for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help!